# I'm trying to show users a different URL when going into a specific page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using modrewrite to show the user a predetermined URL rather than the actual URL access to the page.

this is the configuration that I have in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webtest/index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   new_url.html$ /webtest/user_page.php?TOKEN=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 # If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404’s
 # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
 # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

But it wont show the new URL that I want to show the user

some other URL rather than a number

the top rule is so that the user can access the page correctly and the second one should be for when the user accesses user_page.php that should be masked as another predefined URL name. Also, the TOKEN is alphanumeric and I want to get the TOKEN to query its data

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Comment: @starkeen it's now overwriting my URL so that the user sees another URL rather than the actual one that they see to access my server. I want to hide the URL and only show the token which is a md5() hash